# Uploading files to AWS S3 using Lambda is not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload files to S3 using lambda.
The code is about scrape data from web and make CSV file.

Original code(with out AWS, just scrape and create CSV) is tested and work fine.
So I modified it slightly to work with lambda and s3.

I create S3 bucket.
I made lambda layer.
I made IAM role.(AmazonS3FullAccess)
and I attach it to lambda.

I think I did everything I need. and when I click test button, "Success" is printed.
However, when I check my S3 bucket, there is nothing.

Is there anything I missed? thanks.

Here's my lambda code.

```
const request = require('request');
const Iconv = require('iconv').Iconv;
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv');

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const today = new Date;
const date_string = `${today.getMonth()}/${today.getDate()}`;
const BUCKET_NAME = 'naverfinance';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  
    class Stock {
      constructor(
        name, rank, price, change_inValue, change_inPercent, updown) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.price = price;
        this.change_inValue = change_inValue;
        this.change_inPercent = change_inPercent;
        this.updown = updown;
      }
    }
    
    
    request({ url: 'https://finance.naver.com/sise/sise_quant.nhn', encoding: null }, function(response, body) {

        const euckr_to_utf8 = new Iconv('euc-kr', 'utf8');
        const koreanHTML = euckr_to_utf8.convert(body).toString();
        const $ = cheerio.load(koreanHTML);
        
        let name, rank, price, change_inValue, change_inPercent, updown;
    
        const table = $('.type_2').children('tbody').children('tr'); 
        //3번쨰부터 5개, 빈라인 3개, 이렇게 해서 종목 100개
        
        for(let i = 1; i < table.length; ++i) {
            const tr = table[i];
            if(tr.children.length === 1) {
                continue;
            }
            
            const tds =  tr.children;
            for(let j = 0; j < tds.length; ++j) {
                const td = tds[j];
                if(td.type == 'text') {
                    continue;
                }
                
                const td_data = td.children;            
        
                if(j == 1) {
                    rank = td_data[0].data;
                }
                
                else if(j == 3) {
                    name = td_data[0].children[0].data;
                }
                
                else if(j == 5) {
                    price = parseInt(td_data[0].data.replace(/[,]/g,''));
                }
                
                else if(j == 7) {       
                    let data = 0;
                    
                    if(td_data[2].children != undefined) {
                        data = parseInt(td_data[2].children[0].data.replace(/[\n\t,]/g,''));
                    }
    
                    change_inValue = data;
    
                }
                
                else if(j == 9) {
                    change_inPercent = td_data[1].children[0].data.replace(/[\n\t%]/g,'');
                    
                    if (change_inPercent.indexOf('.') !== -1) { //소수
                        change_inPercent = parseFloat(change_inPercent.replace(/,/g,''));
                    }
                
                    else { //정수
                        change_inPercent = parseInt(change_inPercent.replace(/,/g,''));
                    }
                    
                    if(change_inPercent < 0) {
                        updown = '하락';
                        change_inValue = -change_inValue;
                    }
                    else if(change_inPercent > 0) {
                        updown = '상승';
                        change_inValue = change_inValue;
                    }
                    else {
                        updown = '그대로';
                        change_inValue = 0;
                    }               
                    const stock = new Stock(
                        name, rank, price, change_inValue, change_inPercent, updown);
                    
                    s3.putObject({
                      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                      Key: date_string,
                      ContentType: 'text/plain',
                      Body : 'test' //new ObjectsToCsv(stock).toString()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

after removing async.

```
Response:
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Bad argument.",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Bad argument.",
    "    at convert (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/iconv/index.js:103:11)",
    "    at Iconv.convert (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/iconv/index.js:63:12)",
    "    at Request._callback (/var/task/index.js:28:42)",
    "    at Request.self.callback (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)",
    "    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)",
    "    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)",
    "    at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)",
    "    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)",
    "    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)",
    "    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add any debug (`console.log`) lines to check it is running, this is also an async Lambda function so its possible that it does not wait for the request to finish

Comment: @ChrisWilliams You are right. I put console.log("ok") before, after, and in request. and ok is not printed when console.log is inside of request. What can I do? I tried removing async(error said bad arguments) and I put await in front of request(success but nothing at s3.)

Comment: This is likely the async part of the function, change `exports.handler = async (event)` to `exports.handler = (event)`.

Comment: @ChrisWilliams Thanks for helping. But after changed into `exports.handler = (event)`, I got error message. I put it on original question post because it's too long.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are using an async handler, you need to be returning some kind of response or promise

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html